# Istio on Microk8s not routing

Tags: kubernetes, istio, microk8s, istio-gateway

I am trying to expose the monitoring services of istio: grafana, prometheus, kiali and jaeguer through istio gateway and istio virtual-service but without success

the strange thing is when accessing through the curl the page is returned, but when accessing through the browser the gateway does not find the applications

I've tried it in several ways, put it in the default nasmespace, put it in the istio namespace, recreated the server

any help will be very welcome

- Environment

```
SO: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Kubernetes: Microk8s 1.21/stable 

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21+", GitVersion:"v1.21.1-3+1f02fea99e2268", GitCommit:"1f02fea99e226878ded82f3e159f28a6706ce1fc", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-05-12T21:06:02Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21+", GitVersion:"v1.21.1-3+1f02fea99e2268", GitCommit:"1f02fea99e226878ded82f3e159f28a6706ce1fc", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-05-12T21:02:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Istio: v1.5.1
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSAD3.png)

- yaml config

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-gateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
      - "grafana.myserver.com"
      - "prometheus.myserver.com"
      - "kiali.myserver.com"
      - "jaeger.myserver.com"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: grafana-vs
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - "grafana.myserver.com"
  gateways:
  - istio-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 3000
        host: grafana.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
      weight: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: prometheus-vs
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - "prometheus.myserver.com"
  gateways:
  - istio-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 9090
        host: prometheus.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
      weight: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: kiali-vs
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - "kiali.myserver.com"
  gateways:
  - istio-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 20001
        host: kiali.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
      weight: 100
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: jaeger-vs
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - "jaeger.myserver.com"
  gateways:
  - istio-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: "/"
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 16686
        host: jaeger-query.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
      weight: 100
```

- Istio info

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"istio-ingressgateway","chart":"gateways","heritage":"Tiller","istio":"ingressgateway","release":"istio"},"name":"istio-ingressgateway","namespace":"istio-system"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"status-port","port":15020,"targetPort":15020},{"name":"http2","nodePort":31380,"port":80,"targetPort":80},{"name":"https","nodePort":31390,"port":443},{"name":"tcp","nodePort":31400,"port":31400},{"name":"https-kiali","port":15029,"targetPort":15029},{"name":"https-prometheus","port":15030,"targetPort":15030},{"name":"https-grafana","port":15031,"targetPort":15031},{"name":"https-tracing","port":15032,"targetPort":15032},{"name":"tls","port":15443,"targetPort":15443}],"selector":{"app":"istio-ingressgateway","istio":"ingressgateway","release":"istio"},"type":"LoadBalancer"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-05-21T10:45:05Z"
  labels:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    chart: gateways
    heritage: Tiller
    istio: ingressgateway
    release: istio
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
  resourceVersion: "79445"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/istio-system/services/istio-ingressgateway
  uid: b2a9d401-8ecc-4c3a-bac2-a8db545b80e7
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.152.183.203
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.152.183.203
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: status-port
    nodePort: 30037
    port: 15020
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15020
  - name: http2
    nodePort: 31380
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    nodePort: 31390
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
  - name: tcp
    nodePort: 31400
    port: 31400
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 31400
  - name: https-kiali
    nodePort: 31537
    port: 15029
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15029
  - name: https-prometheus
    nodePort: 32117
    port: 15030
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15030
  - name: https-grafana
    nodePort: 31687
    port: 15031
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15031
  - name: https-tracing
    nodePort: 32132
    port: 15032
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15032
  - name: tls
    nodePort: 32291
    port: 15443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 15443
  selector:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    istio: ingressgateway
    release: istio
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: Are you using different ports in curl and browser ?

Comment: Can you put screenshot of your curl and browser? Your ingress gateway service has an External IP if you do a kubectl get svc -n istio-system? Are you using node's IP to access? That will decide on which port you should access.